# r: Shiny App wordcloud not displaying results

Tags: r, word-cloud

R novice here...

I am trying to create a wordcloud on r shiny app.

Here is what I have in my ui.R:

> ```
>        tabPanel("Word Cloud",
>                sidebarLayout(
>                  # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
>                  sidebarPanel(
>
>                    selectInput("Subcategory", "Choose a 
>                                 Subcategory:",
>                                choices = makeup$SubCategory),
>                    sliderInput("freq",
>                                "Maximum Number of Words:",
>                                min = 1,  max = 7, value = 5),
>                    sliderInput("max",
>                                "Minimum Frequency:",
>                                min = 1,  max = 6000,  value = 1000)
>                  ),
>                  mainPanel(
>                    plotOutput("plot")
>                  ))
> ```

Here is what I have in my server.R:

> ```
>   shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
>
>          word = reactive({
>          myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(subset(makeup, SubCategory == >              input$Subcategory, select = ChemicalName)))
>          myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
>          myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
>          myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
>          myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
>          m = as.matrix(myDTM)
>          v = sort(rowSums(m),decreasing = TRUE)
>          data.frame(word=names(v),freq=v)$word
>          })
>
>      freq = reactive({
>          myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(subset(makeup, SubCategory == >              input$Subcategory, select = ChemicalName)))
>          myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
>          myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
>          myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
>          myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
>          m = as.matrix(myDTM)
>          v = sort(rowSums(m),decreasing = TRUE)
>          data.frame(word=names(v),freq=v)$freq
>          })
>
>
>
>       output$plot <- renderPlot({
>          wordcloud(words = word, 
>                     freq = freq, 
>                     random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.3,   
>                     scale=c(4,.5),max.words=15, 
>                     colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
>           })
> ```

I cannot get my shiny app to display the wordcloud...

I am also getting a warning message:

> .      Warning: Error in max: invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

Any ideas?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

reactives are functions and not variables. Try this - it should work.

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
     wordcloud(words = word(), 
                freq = freq(), 
                random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.3,   
                scale=c(4,.5),max.words=15, 
                colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

@Bertil Baron has the correct answer to your most pressing issue. I thought I would provide some pointers on streamlining your app/code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

     word = reactive({
     myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(subset(makeup, 
                       SubCategory == > input$Subcategory, 
                       select = ChemicalName)))
     myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
     myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
     myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
     myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
     #m = as.matrix(myDTM) ##this can cause an memory error if your corpus is even moderately sized.
     #row_sums from the slam package is much more efficient as it is designed to operate on sparse matrices and TDM/DTMs from the tm package are sparse matrices which are constructed using slam
     v = sort(slam::row_sums(myDTM),decreasing = TRUE)
     data.frame(word=names(v),freq=v) #Since you've already calculated frequency here there is no need for the freq reactive. We can just access the freq from this data.frame
     })

 #this is a redundant reprocessing of your corpus (which can be time consuming if it is big. 
 #freq = reactive({
 #    myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(subset(makeup, SubCategory == >              input$Subcategory, select = ChemicalName)))
 #    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
 #    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
 #    myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
 #    myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)
 #    m = as.matrix(myDTM)
 #    v = sort(rowSums(m),decreasing = TRUE)
 #    data.frame(word=names(v),freq=v)$freq
 #    })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
     wordcloud(words = word()$word,
                freq = word()$freq, 
                random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.3,   
                scale=c(4,.5),max.words=15, 
                colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
      })
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this data, the plot showed up. However, the default page is showing an error, saying invalid 'cex' value. Also the concole returns"Warning in max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in strwidth: invalid 'cex' value" Could you help with that? Thanks a lot!